# Reading Excel files and creating an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have software where coordinates are exported to an xls file, I now want to create a function within MATLAB which uses this xls file but do not wish to change the original software (therefore the xls file will have to remain in the same format).

I am currently using the code

```
FILE = 'KEN FILE2.xls';
[NUM,TXT,RAW]=xlsread(FILE);
xArray = cell2mat(RAW(:,1))
yArray = cell2mat(RAW(:,2))
```

Which is not good enough as my excel file is like the following:

```
 1     2
 2     2.1
 3     2.2  
 4     2.3


 Value of ken 
 27
```

Because of the text in column A the code falls over, I can obviously manually edit the excel file so that my above code works but I would rather have a code that handles this.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the sample input, you have 27 at the end of column A and nothing in B. So do you want 27 to be added to xArray? If so, what about the corresponding element in yArray?

Comment: no 27 doesnt need to be in the array

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find where to cut off you cell array using `ismember`:

```
%//example data
a = {'1';'2';'3';'4';'';'value'};

last = find(ismember(a,''),1)-1;
a_new = a(a:last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code -

```
%%// Read excel file
[NUM,TXT,RAW]=xlsread(FILE);

%// Use this if you think that there might be non-empty cells on third or later 
%// columns, which you do not want to consider.
RAW = RAW(:,1:2); 

%%// Main processing starts now
RAW(cellfun(@ischar,RAW)) = {NaN};
out = cell2mat(RAW);

%%// Use this if you are okay with having NaNs to replace non-numeric data
%RAW = RAW(find(any(out,2)),:); 

%%// Use this if you want to replace all rows having any non-numeric data in them
RAW = RAW(find(all(~isnan(out),2)),:);

%// Use this if you want to stop data import at the first instance of
%// non-numeric data in any row of any column
RAW = RAW(1:find(any(isnan(out),2),1,'first')-1,:); 

%%// Output arrays
xArray = cell2mat(RAW(:,1))
yArray = cell2mat(RAW(:,2))
```

Comment: I tried the last code option and it leaves my x and y array empty?

Comment: I think you have some non-empty cells in third columns or later ones in the excel sheet. So, use "RAW = RAW(:,1:2);" right after xlsread line.

Comment: Yes but that now involves 27, I want the array to finish on the last value before the space. Therefore in this example it would finish with 4

Comment: Just edited. Let us know if it works now with your new requirements!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that last 2 lines (read as `NaN` and `27`) are comments and are separated by 2 empty lines (raed as `NaN`):

```
[NUM,TXT,RAW]=xlsread(FILE);
[m,n]=size(NUM);
% drop off 4 last lines
xArray(:,1)=NUM(1:m-4,1);
yArray(:,1)=NUM(1:m-4,2);
%clean mess
clear NUM TXT RAW m n
```